# XML transformation using XSLT 1.0.multiple pass (group by, count^3, sort) final touch needed

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I think I've created some kind of Frankenstein's monster with this xslt, and I need some help to clean it up and *add some more features*.
Reading up on previous examples I find them either too simple to be of any more help to guide me forward, or too complex for me to understand the sorcery taking place.

**I'm having...** *Source.xml*

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->

<xml>
<data>
    <row arrived="2014-03-08" client="John" location="Venus" outcome="Won"/>
    <row arrived="2014-03-07" client="John" location="Venus" outcome="Lost"/>
    <row arrived="2014-03-07" client="Mark" location="Mars" outcome="Lost"/>
    <!-- note, date range filter in xslt, start... -->
    <row arrived="2014-03-06" client="Louie" location="Mars" outcome="Lost"/>
    <row arrived="2014-03-06" client="Jane" location="Venus" outcome="N/A"/>
    <row arrived="2014-03-04" client="John" location="Tellus" outcome="N/A"/>
    <row arrived="2014-03-04" client="Louie" location="Tellus" outcome="Won"/>
    <row arrived="2014-03-04" client="Steve" location="Tellus" outcome="Lost"/>
    <row arrived="2014-03-02" client="Mark" location="Mars" outcome="Won"/>
    <row arrived="2014-03-02" client="Olga" location="Saturnus" outcome="Lost"/>
    <!-- ...end -->
    <row arrived="2014-03-01" client="Louie" location="Saturnus" outcome="N/A"/>
    <row arrived="2014-03-01" client="Olga" location="Saturnus" outcome="Won"/>
</data>
</xml>
```

**Pass-through...** *Stylesheet.xslt*

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->

<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
    <xsl:output method='xml' omit-xml-declaration='no' encoding='utf-8' indent='yes' />
    <xsl:param name='fromDate' select='20140302' />
    <xsl:param name='toDate' select='20140306' />

    <xsl:key name='location' match="data/row[((number(translate(@arrived, '-', '')) &gt;= $fromDate) and (number(translate(@arrived, '-', '')) &lt;= $toDate))]" use='@location' />

    <!-- I'm lost on this one, might not even be the best way to go about it -->
    <xsl:key name='won' match="data/row[@outcome='Won' and ((number(translate(@arrived, '-', '')) &gt;= $fromDate) and (number(translate(@arrived, '-', '')) &lt;= $toDate))]" use='@outcome' />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <locations>
        <xsl:for-each select="data/row[(count(. | key('location', @location)[1]) = 1) and ((number(translate(@arrived, '-', '')) &gt;= $fromDate) and (number(translate(@arrived, '-', '')) &lt;= $toDate))]">
            <xsl:sort select='@count' order='ascending' /> <!-- not working -->
            <location>
                <xsl:attribute name='name'>
                    <xsl:value-of select='@location' />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name='count'>
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(key('location', @location))"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name='won'>
                    <!--<xsl:value-of select="count(key('won', 'Won'))"/>-->
                    <!--<xsl:value-of select="count(data/row[@outcome='Won'])" />-->
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name='lost'>
                    <!-- (the same way as won) -->
                </xsl:attribute>
            </location>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </locations>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Achieved / Results** (AS-IS)

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<locations>
   <location name="Mars" count="2" won="" lost=""/>
   <location name="Venus" count="1" won="" lost=""/>
   <location name="Tellus" count="3" won="" lost=""/>
   <location name="Saturnus" count="1" won="" lost=""/>
</locations>
```

1. Retrieved only <row>'s having @arrived within given date-range.
2. Group By the retrieved <row>'s (distinct, not unique) based on @location.
3. Added a new @count to <location> to count <row>@location-occurrences within the conditioned date range.

**Missing / Help needed** (+ TO-BE)

What's left to do...

- Get the count on @won + @lost working, (count only within the date range condition).
- A final sort of the resulting <location>'s on a given attribute, (@count, @name, @won or @lost). I.e some kind of `<value sort name="$attribute" type="number|text" order="$order">`

I am using http://xslttest.appspot.com/ to test.

Please help. Preferably with a simple enough and logic solution for me to understand and comprehend the magic happening. Also any clean up tips on what is ugly in the xslt is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See next:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
<xsl:output method='xml' omit-xml-declaration='no' encoding='utf-8' indent='yes' />
<xsl:param name='fromDate' select='20140302' />
<xsl:param name='toDate' select='20140306' />

<xsl:key name='location' match="data/row[((number(translate(@arrived, '-', '')) &gt;= $fromDate) and (number(translate(@arrived, '-', '')) &lt;= $toDate))]" use='@location' />

<!-- I'm lost on this one, might not even be the best way to go about it -->
<xsl:key name='won' match="data/row[@outcome='Won' and ((number(translate(@arrived, '-', '')) &gt;= $fromDate) and (number(translate(@arrived, '-', '')) &lt;= $toDate))]" use='@outcome' />

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <locations>
    <xsl:for-each select="data/row[(count(. | key('location', @location)[1]) = 1) and ((number(translate(@arrived, '-', '')) &gt;= $fromDate) and (number(translate(@arrived, '-', '')) &lt;= $toDate))]">
        <xsl:sort select="count(key('location', @location))" order='ascending' />
        <location>
            <xsl:variable name="currentLocation" select="@location" />
            <xsl:attribute name='name'>
                <xsl:value-of select="$currentLocation" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name='count'>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(key('location', @location))"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name='won'>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(../row[@outcome= 'Won' and @location = $currentLocation and number(translate(@arrived, '-', '')) &gt;= $fromDate and number(translate(@arrived, '-', '')) &lt;= $toDate])" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name='lost'>
                <xsl:value-of select="count(../row[@outcome= 'Lost' and @location = $currentLocation and number(translate(@arrived, '-', '')) &gt;= $fromDate and number(translate(@arrived, '-', '')) &lt;= $toDate])" />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </location>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </locations>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Changes:

- You can't sort on `@count` since it is in the result, NOT in the input. You need to sort on the the way you `count()` it
- Added win/loss with the date range

Comment: Whoa, thanks!!! I'm thinking I might put the string `and number(translate(@arrived, '-', '')) &gt;= $fromDate and number(translate(@arrived, '-', '')) &lt;= $toDate])` in some sort of reusable variable instead of its current multiple occurrences.